# Command Line: Browse to a network path that has spaces and a single quote

Tags: networking, bash, path

I am trying to browse to a network path in dos that has both spaces and a single quote.

When I do:

```
net use "\\server\path's name\folder\"
```

I get an error message that error 53 has occurred.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Internet providers usually block Netbios and windows sharing traffic to reduce virus spreading. There are several other ways you can try accessing your share but anything that comes to mind will require adding additional components into your PE image.

---

**Update :**
The share can have spaces. Just enter it with quotes

eg. `net use F: "\\server\share name"`

Comment: the server in this case is a network resource and not on the external internet

Comment: Did you checked Firewall?

Comment: I think the issue is related to the single quote somehow...

Comment: @AAA  make sure your share folder name has no space or enter it with quotes

Comment: I think so too. Is it possible to check it with another path?

Comment: I entered it with quotes but still no luck